# Color histogram bins by majority class

Tags: r, histogram

I've written a useful function to color histogram bars by the majority class in each bar:

```
color_hist <- function(x, cats, ...){
  hist <- hist(x, plot=FALSE, ...)
  cuts <- cut(x, breaks=hist$breaks)

  color = apply(table(cuts, cats), 1, which.max)

  hist(x, col=color,...)
}

color_hist(iris[,4], iris[,5])
```

[image: color hist]

I'd like to replicate the behavior of `hist()` as much as possible, but I can't figure out how to pass the title and x label from the original histogram to the colorized one:

[image: hist2]

I'd like the new histogram to have the same default title/xlabels as the old histogram, and I'd also like to pass through any other user-specified parameters. Can anyone help me solve this problem, or improve this function in any other way?

(It would also be cool if I could get the colors to blend into each other, depending on the class percentages...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take a look at the code of `hist.default`, how this is handled there...

```
color_hist <- function(x, cats, xlab = xname, main = paste("Histogram of", xname), ...){
  xname <- paste(deparse(substitute(x), 500), collapse = "\n")
  hist <- hist(x, plot=FALSE, ...)
  cuts <- cut(x, breaks=hist$breaks)

  color = apply(table(cuts, cats), 1, which.max)

  hist(x, col=color, xlab = xlab, main = main, ...)
}

color_hist(iris[,4], iris[,5])
```

[image]